# How to use DISTINCT in one column when SELECTING from many columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I'm trying to select columns from two different views but I only want to use the DISTINCT statement on one specific column. I thought using the GROUP BY statement would work but it's throwing an error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            [Act].[ClientId]
    ,       [Ref].[Agency]
    ,       [Act].[FundCode]
    ,       [Act].[VService]
    ,       [Act].[Service]
    ,       [Act].[Attended]
    ,       [Act].[StartDate]
FROM [dbo].[FS_v_CrossReference_ALL] AS [Ref] 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[FS_v_Activities] AS [Act] ON [Ref].[VendorId] = [Act].[VendorId]
WHERE [Act].[StartDate] BETWEEN '1/1/2015' AND '12/31/2015'
GROUP BY [Act].[ClientId]
```

I want to use the DISTINCT statement on `[Act].[ClientId]`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: *I only want to use the DISTINCT statement on one specific column* and what values will all the other columns have?

Comment: It would help to have sample data and expected output.

Comment: If you want to use GROUP BY you have to tell the Select Statement what to do with the other columns (from Agency to StartDate). Normaly, you would use an aggregate function. For example: Select [Act].[ClientId], Max([Ref].[Agency]), Min([Act].[FundCode]) etc. or you must include those columns in your Group By statement as well. You can read more about Group by here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This is usually a "select one from group" situation and you can find discussions about doing so by searching the internet on that phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you want `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ar.*
FROM (SELECT Act.*, Reg.Agency,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Act.ClientId ORDER BY ACT.StartDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM [dbo].[FS_v_CrossReference_ALL] [Ref] JOIN
           [dbo].[FS_v_Activities] Act
           ON [Ref].[VendorId] = [Act].[VendorId]
      WHERE [Act].[StartDate] >= '2015-01-01' AND
            [Act].[StartDate] < '2016-01-01' 
    ) ar
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Particularly note the changes to the date comparisons:

1. The dates are in standard format (YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD).
2. `BETWEEN` is replaced by two inequalities.  This makes the code robust if the date is really a date/time with a time component.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Gordon!